# invalid authencity token (rails, heroku, puma)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, csrf, puma

I was playing around with my rails app (puma server, deployed on heroku) in production, and got the authenticity error when submitted a long form (when I render the form auth token seems to be okay, the value is visible).

Usually the form works well. It was only the second time this has happened. In both cases a long time (~1hour) passed between rendering and submitting the form.

I couldn't find any answer to this problem. Is there a time limit for submitting the form based on when the form was rendered? Or is this a browser issue? It would be important to have this form open for a while since it's pretty long and users may want to think before they fill out the and submit the form.

```
Mar 01 07:36:32 appfaskyn app/web.1:  Started POST "/products" for 141.101.96.195 at 2016-03-01 15:36:31 +0000 
Mar 01 07:36:32 appfaskyn app/web.1:  Processing by ProductsController#create as HTML 
Mar 01 07:36:32 appfaskyn app/web.1:  Can't verify CSRF token authenticity 
Mar 01 07:36:32 appfaskyn app/web.1:  ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken): 
Mar 01 07:36:32 appfaskyn app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:181:in `handle_unverified_request' 
Mar 01 07:36:32 appfaskyn app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:209:in `handle_unverified_request' 
Mar 01 07:36:32 appfaskyn app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.5.6/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:257:in `handle_unverified_request' 
Mar 01 07:36:32 appfaskyn app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:204:in `verify_authenticity_token'
```

Comment: This may be Heroku dyno timing out. Try enabling more than 1 dyno or using newer paid Dynos which won't shut down when idle and see if the problem still happens.

Comment: I'm using one paid dyno, with web_concurrency set to 2 and min/max threads set to 5.